# Подключение к Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, denwer

Нужно установить связку php+oracle. На десктопе стоит денвер и оракл 11. Подключаюсь через oci_connect. При попытке подключения вылетает ошибка:
 Call to undefined function oci_connect()
Что делать?
Код:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'MYDB');
if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
echo "<tr>\n";
foreach ($row as $item) {
echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") .      "</td>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Я совсем новичок в этой сфере, простите за глупый вопрос

Перепробовал всё, что написано [здесь](http://www.sql.ru/forum/676817/podkluchenie-k-oracle). Ничего не помогает

Comment: а это исполнено "Скорее всего 
1. надо установить Oracle Client, 
2. закинуть oci.dll в Apache/bin." ?

Comment: @3per, да сделал.
Если правильно понимаю, для denwer'a путь должен выглядеть как-то так: ...\usr\local\apache\bin
Oracle Client уже предустановлен заранее

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста